# How can images be placed in a webpage title?

Tags: html, title, titlebar

I came accross a webpage: http://pinterest.com/pin/86201780340873856/

When I opened it in my browser I saw that there is an image in the page title
[image: Screenshot of Chrome in Mac]

I'm not referring to the Pintrest logo favicon. I'm referring to the smiley face image.

How can an image be in a page title?

What other images can be placed there?

Does this work with all browsers? If not, what do non supporting browsers show?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're seeing a unicode character in the title, namely , or U+1F604.  In html, this can be displayed with `&#128516;`.  However, different fonts will render it differently (I don't see the colors in your picture), or might not even support it, so you should think twice about using it in your own pages if there is an alternative.

Comment: Is there a resource that shows what fonts are used for the title text by various browsers and the character set they support?

Comment: I've never considered that, but there probably is.  I believe it is OS dependent too, so it might get a little complicated.

Answer (score 2):

It is not an icon, it's a glyph:

U+1F604 SMILING FACE WITH OPEN MOUTH AND SMILING EYES

General Character Properties

In Unicode since: 6.0
Unicode category: Symbol, Other

Various Useful Representations

UTF-8: `0xF0 0x9F 0x98 0x84`

UTF-16: `0xD83D 0xDE04`

C octal escaped UTF-8: `\360\237\230\204`

XML decimal entity: `&#128516;`

Comment: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f604/index.htm